# Not printing else when condition met

Tags: python, if-statement

Hello I am beginner programmer in python and I am having trouble with this code. It is a rock paper scissors game I am not finished yet but it is supposed to print "I win" if the user does not pick rock when the program picks scissors. But when the program picks paper and the user picks rock it does not print "I win". I would like some help thanks. EDIT - answer was to add indent on else before "i win" thank you everybody.

```
import random


ask0 = input("Rock, Paper, or Scissors? ")

list0 = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]

r0 = (random.choice(list0))
print("I pick " + r0)

if ask0 == r0:
    print("Tie")
elif ask0 == ("Rock"):
    if r0 == ("Scissors"):
        print("You Win")
else:
    print("I win")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random


ask0 = input("Rock, Paper, or Scissors? ")

list0 = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]

r0 = (random.choice(list0))
print("I pick " + r0)

if ask0 == r0:
    print("Tie")
elif ask0 == ("Rock"):
    if r0 == ("Scissors"):
        print("You Win")
    else:
        print("I win")
```

Need to add else in Scissors condition.

Answer (score 0):

Once Python as entered the `elif` statement, it will automatically skip the outer `else`. So, if you want it to print "I win" inside the `elif` statement, you need to indent your `else` statement like so:

```
import random

ask0 = input("Rock, Paper, or Scissors? ")

list0 = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]

r0 = (random.choice(list0))
print("I pick " + r0)

if ask0 == r0:
    print("Tie")
elif ask0 == ("Rock"):
    if r0 == ("Scissors"):
        print("You Win")
    else:
        print("I win")
```